# Woo Commerce customized product bundle

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a woo-commerce store and need to make an unique functionality for that store. The feature would be something like, I'll choose first some ingredients and then I'll create a bundle product. Like I'll create a product based on 5 ingredients. Every ingredients has it's own prices. When I make a bundle it will display in the cart as a single product with total ingredients prices. Is it possible in woo-commerce ? A wise advice or plugin reference is greatly welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-bundles/ that plugin seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Nop. I checked that plugin. That serves completely different purpose. I want something like this http://www.mymuesli.com/muesli/index.php?vw=mixer&ec=step1&mnid=1&mnpt=1&type=t0

Comment: [Composite Products](http://www.woothemes.com/products/composite-products/) more closely resembes the muesli website. Each ingredient would correspond to a "component" in the total composite/configured product.